# How to solve Unresolved Reference:java

Tags: kotlin

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        startActivity(Intent(this@SplashScreenActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    },3000)
}
```

At MainActivity::class.java get the error message = "Unresolved References" , How to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.